# Correct way to define handlers in functional React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, nested-function

As far as I know, there are three ways to define functions in JavaScript.

**1. Declaration**

```js
function handleEvent(e) {}
```

**2. Assignment**

```js
var handleEvent = function(e) {}
```

**3. Arrow**

```js
var handleEvent = (e) => {}
```

---

I have been searching for hours trying to find information on which of these options is the preferred way to declare handlers in functional React components. All the articles I found talk about class components, binding, etc. But with the new [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) out, there must be standard for defining them inside the function as well. (After all, functional components have always existed anyway.)

Consider the following component, which declares three handlers, which are examples of different behaviour that you might need in a React component.

```
function NameForm(props) {
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => setInputName(props.initialValue), [props.initialValue]);

    const handleInputChange = function(event) {
        setInputName(event.target.value);
    };

    const resetForm = function() {
        setInputName(props.initialValue);
        props.onReset();
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.onSubmit(inputName);
        resetForm();
    };

    /* React-Bootstrap simple form example using these handlers. */
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="NameForm">
                <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter your name here"
                    value={inputName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                <Button onClick={resetForm}>Reset</Button>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

All of these handlers are directly passed as callbacks into other components. They might be called whenever, but *at that exact moment*, we need to have access to the *current* values of `props` and any state like `inputName`. Additionally, as you might have noticed, the `handleFormSubmit` handler also calls the `resetForm` handler.

**What would be the recommended approach to defining the handlers from a performance perspective?** Can it be avoidable that they are redefined on every render?

Does `useCallback` also fit in here somewhere?

Comment: What you have currently isnt valid javascript. If you intialize a const, you cant just define a function without first setting the const equal to something.

Comment: Ah thanks, it was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

The current standard is to declare the handlers as constants for immutability and as arrow-functions for binding purposes.

```
function NameForm(props) {
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => setInputName(props.initialValue), [props.initialValue]);

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setInputName(event.target.value);
    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setInputName(props.initialValue);
        props.onReset();
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.onSubmit(inputName);
        resetForm();
    }

    /* React-Bootstrap simple form example using these handlers. */
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="NameForm">
                <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter your name here"
                    value={inputName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                <Button onClick={resetForm}>Reset</Button>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

> All of these handlers are directly passed as callbacks into other
>   components. They might be called whenever, but at that exact moment,
>   we need to have access to the current values of props and any state
>   like inputName

As currently constructed we meet the requirements for your description. Since `props` and `state` are defined as higher level data that the component has access to, all the event-handlers have access to them. And when used as a call-back in another component, they will remain bound to the initial component where they were defined in.

Which means if you have an event-handler like this:

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
}
```

And you pass it into a ChildComponent like this:

```
<Child handleInputChange={handleInputChange}/>
```

And the Child uses the prop/event-handler like this:

```
<input onChange={props.handleInputChange}/>
```

You would be getting the `event` from the Child input, but you would be updating the `state` of the Parent, the original component that defined the event-handler.

Comment: So, there is no way to avoid redefining the functions on each render?

Comment: @anddero unfortunately there is not, considering that the component gets re-rendered every time there is a state or props change. However, this is very negligible to performance overall.

Comment: Actually, there is `useCallback`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I believe this answer could be improved, by adding `useCallback` in as well. It prevents redefining the handlers on each render unless certain props change.

Answer (score 5):

There is virtually no difference between the "declaration", "assignment" and "arrow" approaches. The only thing that matters is that you don't always create new instances of the handler functions on each render. For this, use the `useCallback` hook to memoize the function references:

```
const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
  setInputName(event.target.value);
}, []); // `setInputName` is guaranteed to be unique, from the React Hooks docs, so no need to pass it as a dependency

const resetForm = useCallback(() => {
  setInputName(props.initialValue);
  props.onReset();
}, [props.onReset, props.initialValue]; // these come from props, so we don't know if they're unique => need to be passed as dependencies

const handleFormSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit(inputName);
    resetForm();
}, [props.onSubmit, resetForm, inputName]); // `resetForm` and `inputName`, although defined locally, will change between renders, so we also need to pass them as dependencies
```

`useCallback` docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: Are you saying there is really no difference in behavior between the declaration, assignment and arrow approaches? From JavaScript theory it seems otherwise. For example, the assignment and arrow functions are defined when that line of code is executed, but the declaration (1st approach) could be defined earlier with hoisting.

Comment: There are technical differences, yes, like hoisting. But for the sake of your question, that is not important. What's important is that you don't redeclare them with each new render. And `useCallback` does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

In functional component we don't need access to `this`(even more - most linters will give you warning in such a case - and for a reason!). So it does not matter if we use arrow expression or declare a function.

But performance matters. Whatever option from your list you choose it will be recreated on each render. Declaring function itself is not really big deal but:

1. passed down to child it may cause unnecessary re-rendering for PureComponent/`React.memo`-wrapped components.
2. May cause redundant run for `useMemo`/other `useCallback`/`useEffect` if later one includes your handler into dependencies list.

So either declare handler out of the component(once it does not rely on internal state at all) or use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). Beware it needs you explicitly list of all dependencies - don't ignore that. Otherwise result handler may operate on stale data.